# Fast way to return the other element in a list containing two elements in Python

Tags: python-3.x

In Python 3, assume a list `l` contains two object A and B, what is the most elegant way to return B if given A, or A given B?
I could think of

```
[i for i in l if i != A][0]
```

or the other round.

Since this process will be repeated for a large number of times, I want the most efficient way.

Comment: At least to me, it is not very clear what exactly you are asking. Do you mind giving some examples of input lists/conditions and their matching outputs? The arbitrary A and B are a bit confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a ternary operator

```
a=l[0] if l[0]!=A else l[1]
```